# Read audio CD track information

Tags: c#, audio, cd-rom

How can I read the track information (author, track title, length) for an Audio CD using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent tutorial at: http://khason.net/dev/audio-cd-operation-including-cd-text-reading-in-pure-c/

I hope that will be enough, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

hmmm maybe I'm wrong but I think that there is no such information in audio CD. Maybe u must use something like CDDB

Answer (score 2):

"hmmm maybe I'm wrong but I think that there is no such information in audio CD. Maybe u must use something like CDDB"

Oh yes it is, you just can't read it on a PC without 3rd party software see this link [wikipedia CD-Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-Text#Software) the Windows Media player plug-in is particularly nice if all you want to do is read home made CDs

CDDB is only of any use for commercially produced CDs